# DNS: CNAME entry breaks mail

Tags: dns, cname

We have a `www.website.com` on which `www` is CNAME to another website (third party service).

However, when I ask the hosting company to forward `website.com`—without www—to the 3rd party web service, they say that it will break the mail which is hosted locally.

What is the best method to overcome this?

Comment: Let me ask the hosting

Comment: I suspect they have .website.com pointing to a mail server. May be they need to create mail.website.com which points to the mail server, so you can have the empty sub domain. However, there are many considerations here, such as if any one uses .website.com as part of their POP3 or SMTP settings in their mail client

Comment: From Hosting: "The problem is that @ is used for the MX record. When @ will be used for a CNAME record you got problems with the mail. 
"

Comment: Why are you using CNAME at all? Why not just point the A record to the relevant place?

Comment: @Dave if we point our A records to the third party, Mail setup again breaks, dont you think?

Comment: You post says you only point CNAME to third party